# Why I am getting "Problem loading the page" after enabling HTTPS for Apache on Windows 7?

Tags: windows, permissions, ssl-certificate, https, apache-2.2

I enabled HTTPS on the Apache server (2.2.15) Windows 7 Enterprise by uncommenting:

Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-ssl.conf

in C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\conf\httpd.conf and modifying C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\conf\httpd-ssl.conf to include:

DocumentRoot "C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/htdocs"

ServerName myserver.com:443

ServerAdmin admin@dot.com
...

SSLCertificateFile "SSLCertificateFile "C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/conf/cert.pem

SSLCertificateKeyFile "SSLCertificateFile "C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/conf/key.pem"

Then I restart apache (going to start->All Progranms->Apache Server 2.2->Control->restart) and go to localhost on port 443 in Firefox , where I get:

```
<<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title>Index of /</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Index of /</h1>
<ul><li><a href="MyPageLinks/"> Links/</a></li>
.....
....
</ul>
</body></html>
```

But on Display of WebPage I see: 
Unable to connect
Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at localhost.
*The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a few
 moments.
*If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer's network
 onnection.
*If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure
 that Firefox is permitted to access the Web.

I read: Why am I getting 403 Forbidden after enabling HTTPS for Apache on Mac OS X? and added default web server configuration block to match my DocumentRoot

The error Log C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\logs\error.log gives following error:
The Apache2.2 service is running. (OS 5)Access is denied.  : Init: Can't open server certificate file C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/conf/cert.pem

I checked the permissions for cert.pem and it indicates:
All the permissions (Full control, Read, Read and modify, execute, Write) are marked for Admin and I am currently logged in as Admin.

I tried using oldcert.pem and oldkey.pem on the same server and it works fine.

Is there anything that I missed?

Answer (score 1):

The certs that I was using had attribute "Encrypt contents to secure data" enabled. Hence the Apache was not able to read the contents.

I disabled the attribute by right clicking -> properties-> Advanced and removing the check to Encrypt contents to secure data